# Distinct with join in codeigniter mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join, distinct

How can I use Distinct with join in CodeIgniter, I'm trying to fetch customer's name and registered category, but my problem is whiles fetching the data I'm getting data in repetation because of sub-category, I've used distinct but then I'm getting Ambiguous field error, how can I solve this problem.
My View

```
<table class="table table-hover example1">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>SNo.</th> 
    <th>Business Name</th>
    <th>Category Name</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
</tr> 
</thead>
<tbody>
 <?php $i=0;
 foreach($value as $row){ ?>
 <tr>
    <td><?php echo ++$i;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->Bussiness_Name;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->Category_Name;?></td>
    <td onClick="RestoreVendor(<?php echo $row->Business_Id; ?>,<?php echo $row->Trash;?>,'<?php echo $row->Bussiness_Name;?>')" class="btn btn-primary">Remove</td>
 </tr>
 <?php }?>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

My Controller:

```
 public function removecategory()
 {
    $this->load->model('VendorModel');
    $data = $this->VendorModel->remove_category();
    $this->load->view('admin/remove_cat', array('value'=>$data));
 }
```

My Model

```
 public function remove_category()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->distinct('Category_Id');
    $this->db->from('business_mapping');
    $this->db->join('business_profile_details', 'business_profile_details.Business_Id = business_mapping.Business_Id');
    $this->db->join('category_master', 'category_master.Category_Id = business_mapping.Category_Id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

result image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below mentioned query.

```
$query = $this->db->group_by('category_master.Category_Id,business_profile_details.Business_Id');
```

Please try above, It will help you.

Comment: by using this I'm getting one data per category. this isn't working for me.

Comment: I've added screenshot here is the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEk8Y.png

Comment: @StutiRauthan: Glad to help you out from this hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$this->db->distinct();
```

Some times distinct not works then you can use

`$this->db->group_by('business_mapping.unique_coloumn_Name');`

Comment: If I'm using group by I'm getting only a single data.

Comment: I've attached a screenshot of result, I'm getting duplicate data because of sub-category how can I solve this?